# T-sql putting values of column into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have the following table

```
ClassID    StudentID
1          10
1          11
2          12
2          10
3          13
```

I want to have table like this

```
ClassID  StudentID1   StudenID2 ...  StudentID32
1        10           11             null
2        12           10             null
3        3            null           null
```

Is there a way to query above table. Constraint: there could be maximum of 32 (it can be any predefined number) students for each class. I guess while loop can be used somehow, but there should be other ways.

**EDIT**
I've tried to use Pivot, but there I've to use some kind of aggregates, but for above question I don't have to use any kind of aggregate. And in pivot I have to name the column (something like `in(col1, col2,...)`), but here I don't even know ids of students. Is there any general way to solve above simple question so that each row represents a unique ClassID with all students, where each StudentID is in different column (columns can be named anything you like), subject to each ClassID can have max of 32 StudentIDs (I'm not supposed to use self joins because it is not practical)

Comment: you will likely need to use PIVOT. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Sher, looks to me you are missing a column in your source if you are to use a PIVOT to achieve the results you want. The columns in the resulting table are determined by the StudentID, where do the values in these columns come from?

Comment: Hi, @KamranFarzami, exatcly for that reason, I'm not sure whether I should use pivot tables

Comment: By the way, @KamranFarzami, columns should not be exactly StudentID1 and so on.

Comment: What values do the values in the second table represent?

Comment: If 10 is the max, use a ROW_NUMBER() to do the pivot to columns and a MIN(StudentID) as the value. If you don't know how many there will be, then you will need to build a dynamic SQL string.

Comment: @KamranFarzami, I want to retrieve each studentid as different column for each ClassID. For instance, for class with classID = 1 there are 2 students with id's 10 and 11. and each of them should go to second column (StudentID1) and third coulmn (StudentID2) respectively. all toher columns (up to StudentID10) should be null. There could be maximum 10 students in each class

Comment: @Rabbit, thanks I think that will work. I'll try to read more about pivot tables. Yes, max number of students in each class is always predefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you clearly..I still used PIVOT though and here, I assume I don't know the student ID's as well.

```
    create table Student (
    ClassID INT
    , StudentID INT
)

INSERT INTO Student (ClassID, StudentID) VALUES
 (1,10)
, (1,11)
, (2,12)
, (2,10)
, (3,13)

select
    'Student' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150),ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY StudentID)) AS StudentNo
    , *
into #tmpStud
from Student

declare @distinct nvarchar(max) = ''

/*
option a : flexible to the number of students
*/
--set @distinct = (select distinct '[' + StudentNo + '],' as [text()] from #tmpStud for xml path(''))
--set @distinct = SUBSTRING(@distinct, 0, LEN(@distinct))

/*
option b : max of 32 student
*/
declare @max int = 33
        , @loop int = 1

while (@loop < @max)
    begin
        if(@loop = 1) begin
            set @distinct = @distinct + '[Student' + Convert(nvarchar(20),@loop) + ']'
            set @loop = @loop + 1
        end
        else begin
            set @distinct = @distinct + ',[Student' + Convert(nvarchar(20),@loop) + ']'
            set @loop = @loop + 1
        end
    end

exec ('
select
    *
from (
    select
        ClassID
        , StudentNo
        , StudentID
    FROM #tmpStud
) AS s PIVOT
(
    MAX(StudentID)
    FOR StudentNo IN (' + @distinct + ')
) AS pvt
')

drop table #tmpStud
```

**EDIT :** Once you have your create table student, please run the below code :

```
select
    'Student' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150),ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY StudentID)) AS StudentNo
    , *
into #tmpStud
from Student

declare @distinct nvarchar(max) = ''

/*
option a : flexible to the number of students
*/
set @distinct = (select distinct '[' + StudentNo + '],' as [text()] from #tmpStud for xml path(''))
set @distinct = SUBSTRING(@distinct, 0, LEN(@distinct))

exec ('
select
    *
from (
    select
        ClassID
        , StudentNo
        , StudentID
    FROM #tmpStud
) AS s PIVOT
(
    MAX(StudentID)
    FOR StudentNo IN (' + @distinct + ')
) AS pvt
')

drop table #tmpStud
```

**EDIT :** Lets assume you'll be needed a static of 32 students @ max..use the script below.

```
select
    'Student' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150),ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY StudentID)) AS StudentNo
    , *
into #tmpStud
from Student

declare @distinct nvarchar(max) = ''

/*
option b : static max of 32 student
*/
declare @max int = 33
        , @loop int = 1

while (@loop < @max)
    begin
        if(@loop = 1) begin
            set @distinct = @distinct + '[Student' + Convert(nvarchar(20),@loop) + ']'
            set @loop = @loop + 1
        end
        else begin
            set @distinct = @distinct + ',[Student' + Convert(nvarchar(20),@loop) + ']'
            set @loop = @loop + 1
        end
    end

exec ('
select
    *
from (
    select
        ClassID
        , StudentNo
        , StudentID
    FROM #tmpStud
) AS s PIVOT
(
    MAX(StudentID)
    FOR StudentNo IN (' + @distinct + ')
) AS pvt
')

drop table #tmpStud
```

Comment: it seems seems that it should work. But query returns error. distinct is not declared, I've fixed it. And now error is Incorrect syntax near ')'.
I can't fix this error. Could you please edit your answer. Thanks

Comment: yeah, my apology, the @distinct data type should be nvarchar(max)

Comment: yeah, I did it, but anyway it returns error described in my previuos comment. Could you please review query

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks. I'll try to understand the query now. Take your bounty (after 10 hours))

Comment: I actually have an option B if in case you need a "static" 32 students, i'll paste the next query for that if ever you need..hold on

Comment: That will be super. like if there is only 2 students in all classes, student ids from 3 to 32 will be written as null))

Comment: Done, kindly see the latest edit, that should hopefully helps.

Comment: Can I take the bounty? I think you should assign it..ahaha

Comment: Sure, I wrote in previous comments. But I have to wait 10 hours(site policy) more to assign it. Thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

With a known limit that is relatively small (e.g. 10), a self join would work.

Comment: One moment, I'm fixing the answer.

Comment: thanks but it is not a solution. Limit can be any predefined number. I wrote 10 just to explain my problem

Comment: I have removed the code from the answer since a self join is not workable when there is not a small fixed limit like 10.

Comment: I would consider doing this on the client side.  Though SQL Server has a pivot facility (at least since 2008) I think it's a bit of abuse of the server's role which is to maintain and deliver data, not present it to the user.  Pivoting the data as you describe is really a data presentation operation.  Tables and query results sets are not spreadsheets though they may trivially appear so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of Count(), GROUP BY, temp tables  and PIVOT function.

I have the following for the example above and it seems to work. You can modify the Pivot to derive the column names dynamically, but this requires a bit of thought.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT ClassID,
                COUNT(StudentID) AS StudentNum
         FROM KamTest.dbo.Table1
         GROUP BY ClassID)
     SELECT A.ClassID,
            B.StudentID,
            A.StudentNum INTO #temp
     FROM CTE AS A
     INNER JOIN
     KamTest.dbo.Table1 AS B
     ON A.ClassID=B.ClassID;

SELECT ClassID,
       MAX(StudentID),
       COUNT(StudentID)
FROM KamTest.dbo.Table1
GROUP BY ClassID;

SELECT ClassID,
       [10] AS StudentID10,
       [11] AS StudentID11,
       [12] AS StudentID12,
       [13] AS StudentID13
FROM(
    SELECT ClassID,
           StudentID,
           StudentNum
    FROM #temp) AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX(StudentNum) FOR StudentID IN([10],
                                                                      [11],
                                                                      [12],
                                                                      [13])) AS PivotTable;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't list all student ids for each class in different columns

Comment: that's in the column header. You can play around with it and modify it to suit your needs